# Java how to in-force Generic type

Tags: java, generics

Below is code sample which I working on.

```
interface KafkaRecord {}

class Book implements KafkaRecord { 
    //some properties here with getter setter
}

class BookDeserializer implements Deserializer<Book> {
    //Deserialiazing bytes to Book 
}


// props is Properties which having key value pair for configuration. 
Consumer<String, KafkaRecord> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
ConsumerRecords<String, KafkaRecord> records = 
        consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(getTimeout()));

records.foreach(bean -> SomeComponent.process((Book) bean));
```

This work as expected. I created another bean Pencil and forgot to implement KafkaRecord, and below code is still working.

```
class Pencil {
  //some getters and setters
}

class PencilDeserializer implements Deserializer<Pencil> {
  //Deserialiazing bytes to Pencil
}

// props is Properties which having key value pair for configuration.
Consumer<String, KafkaRecord> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props); 

// Pencil does not implement KafkaRecord
ConsumerRecords<String, KafkaRecord> records =
        consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(getTimeout()));

records.foreach(bean -> SomeOtherComponent.process((Pencil) bean));
```

ConsumerRecords definition(kafka-clients-2.4.0.jar):

```
public class ConsumerRecords<K, V> implements Iterable<ConsumerRecord<K, V>> {
    //Behavior and getter/setters
}
```

Seems like below issue is happening because of generic erasure. How can I fix this issue ?

After some more digging -

Internal working from AbstractConfig.java-
For setting deserilizer -

1. Its calling getClass(key) //key is coming from configuration
2. It then create instance which it got from step 1.
3. Then it cast to Class t(where t is Deserializer, in our case T should be KafkaRecord)

What I believe is that as run time type is not present, it allowing to set `Deserializer<Pencil>` to be set in first place. So its able to deserialize it and able to assign it in `ConsumerRecords<String, KafkaRecord> records`, as type is not there.

Sample GIT - https://github.com/jitendraVishnoi/kafka

Edit -
I added antoher method in CustomExecutor.java -

```
private void playWithRecord(KafkaRecord record) {
    System.out.println("Record class: " + record.getClass()); // Record class: class kafka.beans.Pencil
    System.out.println("record instanceof KafkaRecord: " + (record instanceof KafkaRecord)); // record instanceof KafkaRecord: false
    System.out.println("record instanceof Pencil: " + (record instanceof Pencil)); // record instanceof Pencil: true
    System.out.println("toString() :" + record); // toString() :Pencil{color='Red'}
  }
```

and which being called from-

```
ConsumerRecords<String, KafkaRecord> pencilRecords = pencilConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
pencilRecords.forEach(bean -> playWithRecord(bean.value()));
```

first line works but second line break with ClassCastException.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: kafka.beans.Pencil cannot be cast to kafka.beans.KafkaRecord
        at CustomExecutor.lambda$run$0(CustomExecutor.java:28)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source)
        at CustomExecutor.run(CustomExecutor.java:28)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If we update playWithRecord() to accept argument of type Object instead of KafkaRecord it works.

Looks to me its happening as Type has been erased for -

```
ConsumerRecords<String, KafkaRecord> pencilRecords = pencilConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
```

Comment: If the code is working, what is the problem?

Comment: How would we know, given that we have no idea what `ConsumerRecords` is, how its method `foreach()` is declared? --- But basically, your code is bypassing type safety by **casting**, and you're now asking how to make the code type-safe? Answer: Stop casting!

Comment: @Sweeper - Yes code is working. Problem is ConsumerRecords<String, KafkaRecord> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(getTimeout())); // Pencil does not implement KafkaRecord
As consumer.poll return Pencil object and left side is not complaining about.

Comment: @Andreas - public class ConsumerRecords<K, V> implements Iterable<ConsumerRecord<K, V>> {}, Its from kafka-clients-2.4.0.jar
as metioned in previous comment I am concerned about while poll worked fine. in 2nd line I did casting as I was thinking I getting Pencils and its fine to cast them.

Comment: Don't show code in a comment. **Edit** the question and show the code there to clarify the question, and where the code can be better formatted for human readability.

Comment: I have made an attempt to format your code in a more sensible / readable fashion.  But you still need to explain what you are actually asking **IN THE QUESTION**.

Comment: @StephenC - Is there any way I can report this issue while writing code.  That Pencil must implement KafkaRecord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is happening because of generic erasure. https://coderanch.com/t/739304/java/Java-Generic-run-time

I had to discuss this in another forum as I was not getting much response here. @Stephen has already explained how to force java to report it compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not a generic type / erasure problem at all.

Consider this:

```
SomeOtherComponent.process((Pencil) bean))
```

At compile time, the question is: can `bean` ... which we know implements `KafakaRecord` ... possibly be `Pencil` or some subclass of `Pencil`?

Now we know that it can't be an instance of `Pencil`, because `Pencil` does not implement `KafakaRecord`.   But suppose I declare the following:

```
class ColoredPencil extends Pencil implements KafkaRecord {
    ...
}
```

If our `records` collection *at runtime* consisted of `KafkaRecord` instances that were `ColouredPencil` objects, then they *would* be instances of `Pencil`, so the type cast should not be a compile time error.

In general, a cast from an interface type to a class type is NOT a compile time error, *unless* the class type is `final` *and* the class does not directly or indirectly implement the interface.

---

> Is there any way I can report this issue while writing code. That Pencil must implement `KafkaRecord`.

Not with the code as written.

You could try this approach:

```
interface <T extends KafkaRecord> KafkaDeserializer extends Deserializer<T> {}

class PencilDeserializer implements KafkaDeserializer<Pencil> {
     // Deserialiazing bytes to Pencil
}
```

The latter will give a compilation error if `Pencil` hasn't been declared as a subtype of `KafkaRecord`.  That might be sufficient for your needs, especially if you can ensure that all of your deserializers implement `KafkaDeserializer` rather than `Deserializer`.  (I don't know enough about Kafka to know if this *actually* makes sense.)

And another approach would be to simply declare `Pencil` as `final`.

Comment: Thank you Stephen for your time to answer the query. I have added GIT url for clarification.  Another thing is Pencil does not extend/implement any class/interface related with KafkaReocrd but line L26 in CustomExecutor.java works fine. What can be done so this issue can be report at compile/run time.

Comment: Thank you Stephen for detailed explanation. One more question doesn't Java check at runtime if Pencil object is coming and being passed in KafkaRecord(where Pencil and  KafkaRecord don't have any relationship) type variable.